# Исчезает список в ListFragment при повороте телефона

Tags: android, android-fragment, listview, android-linearlayout

В приложении с `DrawerLayout` при нажатии на кнопку "add account" в заголовке левого Drawer я показываю `ListFragment` со списком из шести соц. сетей:

[image: screenshot]

Сперва `ListFragment` выглядит (почти) как нужно - но при повороте почему-то исчезает (или очищается?) список соц. сетей и я видимо не понимаю какой-то простой вещи, почему это происходит и как решить эту проблему.

Вот код в **MainActivity.java** обрабатывающий нажатие на "add account":

```
public void showAccounts(View v) {
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mLeftDrawer);

    final AccountFragment fragment = new AccountFragment();
    fragment.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            Utils.ACCOUNT_LABELS) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView view = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            view.setCompoundDrawablePadding(24);
            view.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(Utils.ACCOUNT_ICONS[position], 0, 0, 0);
            return view;
        }
    });

    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .replace(R.id.root, fragment, Utils.ACCOUNTS)
                    .commit();
        }
    }, DRAWER_CLOSE_DELAY_MS);
}
```

Вот показваемый потом **AccountFragment.java**:

```
public class AccountFragment extends ListFragment {
    public AccountFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeToast(getContext(), "You have clicked " + Utils.ACCOUNT_LABELS[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

И соответствующий **fragment_account.xml** (с парой дополнительных проблем):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/photo"
        app:border_width="2dp"
        app:border_color="#FFF"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Username"
        />                      <!-- почему-то не в центре -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>                 <!-- не уверен насчет высоты -->

</LinearLayout>
```

В отладчике видно, что при повороте телефона вызывается заново `onCreateView()` - но почему это очищает или прячет `ListView`?

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ:** Я передвинул вызов `setListAdapter()` в `onAttach()` - как было предложено Eugene Krivenja (спасибо!) [в тестовом проекте на GitHub](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/q38/RotatedList) и теперь список не исчезает при повороте телефона.

Осталась только косметическая проблема с двумя `TextView`s из [fragment_account.xml](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q38/RotatedList/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_account.xml) не в середине экрана (помечены красной стрелкой):

[image: screenshot]

Comment: По тексту по центру - думаю в атрибутах  `TextView` вместо параметров `android:textAlignment="center"` или `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` нужно установить гравити внутри виджета, а не выравнивание текста или гравити относительно родительского лэйаута: `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` - должно решить вашу проблему

Comment: `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` и `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` помогло!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что фрагмент персоздается системой с помощью конструктора без параметров. И все. Соответственно, этот код

```
fragment.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        Utils.ACCOUNT_LABELS) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView view = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        view.setCompoundDrawablePadding(24);
        view.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(Utils.ACCOUNT_ICONS[position], 0, 0, 0);
        return view;
    }
});
```

не выполняется.

Перенесите его в `AccountFragment.onAttach()` и все будет Ок.